# GetProperties() order is not consistent (.NET Core 2 & .NET Core 3)

Tags: .net-core, c#-8.0

I use reflection to get the property list of a class. I need to get the names in the exact same order as they are declared in the code.

When I only call `typeof(TypeOfClass).GetProperties()` I get the properties in the good order.

Some code added in my project made some reflection reads that brake my build.

It took a while to find it but after a couple hours, I've found that you get a property by name `GetProperty("name")` it can change the order on further call of `GetProperties()`

Here is the code (Console App) to reproduce the same issue:

```cs
class Program
    {
        private class SomeClass
        {
            public int IntProperty { get; set; }
            public string StringProperty { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",propertyInfos.Select(p => p.Name)));
            //Output: IntProperty, StringProperty, DateProperty
        }
    }
```

Same code with an access to `GetProperty` before `GetProperties`

```cs
class Program
    {
        private class SomeClass
        {
            public int IntProperty { get; set; }
            public string StringProperty { get; set; }
            public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PropertyInfo dateProp = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("DateProperty");

            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",propertyInfos.Select(p => p.Name)));
            //Output: DateProperty, IntProperty, StringProperty
        }
    }
```

If you execute the 2nd code block, it will return the properties with the DateProperty as the first index!?

Does anybody knows why, Is there a way to ensure that GetProperties will always return the same list in the same order?

PS: I've only tried this with .netcore 3.1. I assume that this might not be a bug in previous versions.

Thanks

Comment: FYI: .Net Framework 4.7 does not have the issue, just tested it... the probleme is there also in .Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *CallerLineNumberAttribute Class* It allows you to obtain the line number in the source file at which the method is called. Only in this case, you can be sure of the order of properties. This is works for me:

```
 private class SomeClass
 {
    [Order]
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    [Order]
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    [Order]
    public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }

   }
```

This will let the compiler **insert order** into your properties:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
 public sealed class OrderAttribute : Attribute
 {
    private readonly int order_;
    public OrderAttribute([CallerLineNumber]int order = 0)
    {
       order_ = order;
    }

    public int Order { get { return order_; } }
  }

PropertyInfo dateProp = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("DateProperty");

var propertyInfos = from property in typeof(SomeClass).GetProperties()
                                where Attribute.IsDefined(property, 
                                typeof(OrderAttribute))
                                orderby ((OrderAttribute)property
                                   .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OrderAttribute), false)
                                    .Single()).Order
                                select property;



Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", propertyInfos.Select(p => p.Name)));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Didn't know about CallerLineNumberAttribute compiling attribute,  To use with moderation I guess..

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you can't. [As stated in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netcore-3.1):

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies.

The order in which the properties are returned are considered an implementation detail, and you cannot rely on that order.

To determine the order in which the properties are defined in the source code, you'll need access to the source code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the documentation. I know this is not best-practice to use code/declaration order but..., Upvoted but took the solution with Attributes because I generate a dynamic SqlBulkCopy data reader that need/require to have the columns in the same order (required by streaming). Thank you again.